# Average of data-points

Tags: average

I am trying to solve clustering problem. After step 1 i.e putting each data-point to a cluster now I want to calculate the mean or average of all of the data-points in a specific cluster. let suppose I have some data-points like A(2,3), B(4,5), C(6,7), D(8,9) in a cluster. How can I calculate their average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of 2 ways, depending on what you need.

**Average of points is a point**

If so, then average each coordinate separately to get the center of mass $C$

**Average of points is a number**

You can then compute average distance from the center of mass $C$ above, or compute all pairwise distances in the cluster and average those.

Comment: I have calculated like this please do have a look and tell me is it okay?
[{(2+4+6+8)/4},{(3+5+7+9)/4}=(5,6)

Comment: @ZeeshanNisar this is the first way in my answer